How can I pass the id when clicking on the Delete button
I'm new and looking for a way to include dynamic id in the examples in the tutorial here.
Because all REST Admin API queries require a valid Shopify access token, all example must use inside headers, action and loader function.
I make code example with the Remix code:
export const loader = async ( { request, params } ) => {
    const { admin, session } = await authenticate.admin( request );

    const data = await admin.rest.resources.Asset.all({
        session: session,
        theme_id: params.id, // Pass id here
        asset: {"key": "sections/header.liquid"}
    });

    return json( { data } );
}

const App = () => {
    const { data } = useLoaderData();
    console.log( data );

    return (
                // Is there any way without using Form and useActionData?
        <button id="136012988610" onClick={ /* Pass this button id when click */ }>Delete section from this theme</button>
    );
};

export default App;

// Update image.
Select theme ID to delete

Pass theme ID to do it, document here

I want when I click on the Delete button, the corresponding id will be transmitted for processing. I've been struggling for a long time but still can't find a way to handle it.
Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions that can assist me?
Thank you guys

you want to pass the id="136012988610" to the onclick function as a param right?

Hi @DileepaMabulage
Yes, but it requires authentication permission as shown in the tutorial link, which must be used in headers, action and loader function

I didn't get that, do you want to implement the admin authentication also

No, just pass id when clicking to button

What are you trying to pass an id value to? Why not pass it in the button's onClick handler? Maybe you could [edit] your post to clarify and provide more details what the specific issue is you are trying to solve for, and provide a more complete, accurate, and representative [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Hi @DrewReese, i have update my image, can you check again?

I think you are misunderstanding us. Try just passing the id to the handler, e.g. onClick={() => handler("136012988610")} and then do what you need with it from there.

To handle a button click event in a React component and pass the button's ID, we can use event object.
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

    const handleDelete = (event) => {

        // Retrieve the button ID from the event object
        const buttonId = event.target.id;

        console.log(`Button with ID ${buttonId} was clicked`);
        
    };

    return (
        <button id="136012988610" onClick={handleDelete}>
            Delete section from this theme
        </button>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;


Hi, that's right but this is not a pure react example, it is code on Remix react Shopify as I stated in the question, can you extend it?

Why do you think this won't work? Or do you want an exact answer?

Hi, i have update my image, can you check again?
